# Problem in project.properties file in building pgs4a project

Tags: python, android, python-2.7, build, apk

I am building a pygame apk using pgs4a. When I run 
`android.py build mygame release`
This is what I get:

```
Updating build files.  

Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Added file F:\pgs4a-master\build.xml
Updated file F:\pgs4a-master\proguard-project.txt

Creating assets directory.


Packaging internal data.

Listing private ...
Listing private\include ...
Listing private\include\python2.7 ...
Listing private\lib ...
Listing private\lib\PIL ...
Listing private\lib\android ...
Compiling private\lib\android\__init__.py ...
Compiling private\lib\android\apk.py ...
Compiling private\lib\android\mixer.py ...
Listing private\lib\encodings ...
Listing private\lib\json ...
Listing private\lib\pygame ...
Listing private\lib\pygame\threads ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7 ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\bsddb ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\compiler ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\config ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\distutils ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\distutils\command ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\email ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\email\mime ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\encodings ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\hotshot ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\importlib ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\json ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\lib-dynload ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\logging ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\multiprocessing ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\multiprocessing\dummy ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\plat-linux3 ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\pydoc_data ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages\android ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages\jnius ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pygame ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pygame\threads ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\sqlite3 ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\sqlite3\test ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\unittest ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\wsgiref ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml\dom ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml\etree ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml\parsers ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml\sax ...
Listing private\lib\sqlite3 ...
Listing mygame ...
Compiling mygame\rotating_cube.py ...

I'm using Ant to build the package.

Buildfile: F:\pgs4a-master\build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at F:\pgs4a-master\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MYCUbe-1.0
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:

BUILD FAILED
F:\pgs4a-master\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:459: ../../google-play-services_lib resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project F:\pgs4a-master

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Although I have searched and tried enough to get it correct but I failed to do so. The other sources seem to be confusing as they are seem to be related to something else(I am using pgs4a). I am working on windows10. Actually I am confused about `project.properties` file (there are many files of this name),which one should I edit and which path should I give in this file(as cited on various sources,it seems very confusing). I have tried many solutions but confused. A good explanation would be appreciated. It is one of the last steps (after many other problems earlier too in this path),so I just want to complete it. Very thanks in advance.

Comment: The directory containing pgs4a(downloaded ) name is pgs4a-master and my directory containing my project rotating_cube.py is mygame(inside the pgs4a-master directory.

Comment: The project.properties file in directory pgs4a-master (outside mygame directory)reads                                                                                                                        `target=android-19`
`android.library.reference.1=../../google-play-services_lib`

Comment: The path to my google-play-services_lib folder is pgs4a-master/android-sdk/extras/google/google-play-services/libproject/google-play-services_lib which also contains a project.properties file which reads:                                                                `target=android-10`
`android.library=true`